# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre npx create-react-app vs expo init en React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Según la documentación de React Native:

```
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
```

Para instalar y crear una carpeta de proyecto para nuestra aplicación se basa a la siguiente línea de código `expo init testing` esta me crea una carpeta `testing` doy click en propiedades y tiene `0 bytes` esto es antes de ejecutar una de las opciones a elegir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono una de las opciones, en este caso seleccione `blank` que tengo entendido que es una plantilla en blanco y luego esta procede a instalar, descargar los componentes o archivos a nuestra carpeta `testing`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una variedad de tamaño de archivos descargados al realizarlo de esta manera `expo init testing` a diferencia de esta otra forma `npx create-react-app my-app` incluso las indicaciones al culminar las descargas los menú e indicaciones son muy distintas entre la otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cual es la diferencia entre `expo init testing` y esta otra `npx create-react-app my-app` afecta el rendimiento, o existirán componentes, archivos, librerías que pueda ocasionar errores en el desarrollo de la APP.

Answer (score 3):

Mira básicamente la diferencia entre expo init testing y npx create-react-app es que uno inicia un proyecto en REACT NATIVE y el otro un proyecto en REACT. Con expo o sea react native tenes dos caminos posibles usar expo (fácil para empezar) o usar CLI de react native. Estas dos opciones las vas a encontrar [acá](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Luego por otro lado tenes un proyecto de react, de una aplicación web utilizando un modulo creado por [facebook](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Resumiendo uno es para hacer aplicaciones móviles y el otro crear aplicaciones web.

Answer (score 1):

`npx create-react-app` y `expo init` son comandos que básicamente generan una serie de archivos base para comenzar a desarrollar una aplicación. Ninguno de los dos es realmente necesario, sino que son plantillas con código comunmente usado para ahorrar algo de tiempo.

El comando `npx create-react-app` creará los arhivos para una aplicación web, más especificamente una SPA o Single Page Application (traducido al español sería una aplicación de una página). Si bien este tipo de páginas pueden ser escaladas hacia una PWA (Progressive Web Application) para adaptarse a una experiencia como la de un móvil, estas viven en la web y son accesibles a través del buscador o de una IP.

El comando `expo init`, por otro lado, generará archivos para una aplicación móvil usando  Expo, un conjunto de herramientas que se encarga de mover Javascript a código nativo de dispositivos, basándose en React Native. Este último es muy parecido a React, cuenta con los mismos conceptos, sin embargo las aplicaciones que crearemos aquí las podremos publicar solamente en tiendas de aplicaciones móviles (Play Store, App store) o en la web de Expo.

En resumen, Create React App sirve para generar una plantilla para aplicaciones web, mientras que Expo init lo hará para aplicaciones móviles.